# Size of a non-plated throughole (NPTH) for a spacer

Tags: pcb, mounting-holes

I am designing a PCB. For spacer, I would like to use this part:
http://www.keyelco.com/product-pdf.cfm?p=4805

The diameter of this spacer is 0.25 inches. 
What should be the size of hole on the PCB? should I use the same dia 0.25 inches for the NPTH holes?

Comment: How are you mounting what is going on the standoff? That would more so dictate your hole size.

Comment: Sorry it's a spacer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inside diameter of the spacer is 0.144 inch.  I would make the hole in the board 0.144 inch as well - or big enough to pass the fastener you will be using.

The outside diameter of the spacer is 0.25 inch - if you make the hole in the board that size, the spacer will fall through the board.

Answer (score 1):

The diameter of the hole in the PCB is determined by... the diameter of the *screw* that does into the hole.  The diameter of the screw mustn't exceed the inner diameter of the spacer (which is 0.144 inch, or 3.66 mm).

For the purposes of discussion, let's assume that the mounting screw is an M3.  We go to a [tap&drill chart](http://www.csgnetwork.com/screwmetmachtable.html) and look-up the drill diameter for the fit that we would like.  Let's say for the purposes of discussion, that we can tolerate some slop, and we'd like a free fit.  Then the hole diameter should be 3.6 mm.

[image]

[Ash's profile points to Arizona.  The same applies to American numbered screw sizes as well.]